# "We are back next week" vs "We will be back next week"

Tags: grammar

"We are back next week" vs "We will be back next week"
What is the difference between these two sentences? Which one is preferred over another?

Answer (score 1):

You could argue that the first is incorrect, but it is often used anyway by native speakers, generally with "we are" being contracted to "we're". I would definitely avoid using the first in writing, and the second is safer in every case.

As "being back next week" is a state that one achieves in the future, using future tense is best.

Note that, with verbs, one can use the present continuous form in a similar way that is completely valid for talking about future events. For example:

> We are coming back next week

But this only applies when you use a "to be" verb (such as "are") plus the present participle of another verb. It is not correct (based on how tolerant you are of the "living language" idea) to omit the present participle verb.

The above example is equivalent to:

> We will be coming back next week

Answer (score 0):

The first is incorrect as it mixes up the tenses.  To use "are" is a present tense, so you cannot use it to discuss something which will not happen until next week (future tense).